# Ruby IMAP Net::IMAP::DataFormatError: nil when not using date

Tags: ruby, gmail, imap, rubymine

Setting: using RubyMine 4.5 and Ruby 1.9.3

This following is the full code I have in a method to search my email and the has one variable in which is the emailaddress which is being passed in with no problems.

The error I recieve during debug is Net::IMAP::DataFormatError: nil on line `messagebody = imap.fetch(imapindex.first,"BODY[TEXT]")` but when I use the same lines in irb it works fine.

```
    imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, true)
    imap.login('someemailaddress@gmail.com','somerandommailpass')
    imap.select('INBOX')
    Log.info emailaddress
    imapindex = imap.search(["TO", emailaddress])
    messagebody = imap.fetch(imapindex.first,"BODY[TEXT]")
    imap.store(imapindex, "+FLAGS", [:Deleted])
    imap.logout
    imap.disconnect
    Log.info messagebody
    return messagebody
```

Any incite would be helpful

Thanks